# Is the fundamental group of any compact hyperbolic 3-manifold embeddable into a p-adic group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory, open-problems, 3-manifolds

Is it true that for every compact hyperbolic $3$-manifold $M$ there exists a prime $p$, a  finite field extension $K/\mathbb{Q}_p$, and an injective group homomorphism $$\tau \colon \pi_1(M) \to \mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathcal{O}_K) ?$$

Here $\mathcal{O}_K$ is the ring of integers of $K$.

This question is obviously related to the existence of faithful low dimensional representation of hyperbolic groups (see the following [survey by Aschenbrenner, Friedl, and Wilton](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.0202.pdf)).

An affirmative solution will give a (partial) confirmation of Conjecture 1 from this [paper by Luo](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.2228.pdf).

A [paper by Calegari and Emerton](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~fcale/papers/Fritz.pdf) also discusses such group homomorphisms $\tau$.

Note that the answer is obviously 'yes' if $M$ is arithmetic.

Comment: Conjecture 1 in Luo's paper you mention says that $\pi_1(M)$ is residually embeddable into $PSL_2$ of finite commutative rings. But this follows from $\pi_1(M)$ being embeddable into $PSL_2$ of a field, not necessarily in the rings of integers of a $p$-adic field. So it's true (with old methods) unless I have a misunderstanding.

Comment: @YCor I am sorry but I do not understand your comment. Do you suggest that the implication I mention in the question is wrong?

Comment: I'm saying that Conjecture 1 in Luo's paper sounds to me as a simple standard exercise. Namely, for every finitely generated subgroup $G$ of $PSL_2(\mathbf{C})$ and every $g\in G-\{1\}$, there exists a finite field $K$ and a homomorphism $G\to PSL_2(K)$ mapping $g$ to a nontrivial element.

Comment: @YCor Why such a field $K$ exists? By the way, this conjecture is also mentioned in the survey of Aschenbrenner, Friedl, and Wilton.

Comment: Proof. First let $G'$ be the inverse image of $G$ in $SL_2$. Let $R$ be the ring generated by entries of $G'$. Let $g\in G$ with $g\neq 1$ and $g'$ a lift in $G'$ of $g$. Let $b$ be a nonzero entry of $g'-1$ and $c$ a nonzero entry of $g'+1$. Since every f.g. domain is residually a finite field (this is part of the usual proof that f.g. linear groups are residually finite), there exists a finite quotient field $K$ of $R$ in which $bc\neq 0$. So the image of $g'$ in $SL_2(K)$ is neither 1 nor $-1$. So $G'\to PSL_2(K)$ factors through $G$ and maps the image of $g$ to a nontrivial element.

Comment: @YCor is there somewhere a hyperbolicity assumption in your proof? Maybe when you assume that the group is linear?

Comment: OK the conjecture in the paper is for arbitrary compact 3-manifolds. In the hyperbolic case (which was part of your assumptions) it follows by the above argument, and more generally if $\pi_1(M)$ has a faithful rep in $PSL_2$ of a field.

Comment: @YCor - Exactly!

Comment: A group that is residually embeddable in $PSL_2$ of finite commutative rings will be embeddable in $PSL_2$ of a finitely generated (pass to the product and then restrict to suitable entries). So it maps with nilpotent kernel into a finite product of $PSL_2$ over fields.

Comment: There's a confusion in the conjecture in Luo's version and in the AFW version. In the first, the target is $PSL_2(R)$, but the latter is not defined. It leaves a little ambiguity (how do you define $PSL_2$ over a ring?). In the AFW survey, $PSL_2$ is replaced with $SL_2$, which leaves no ambiguity but it might have trivial counterexamples then.

Comment: The naive definition $PSL_2(R)=SL_2(R)/\{\pm 1\}$ is not satisfactory because it would not satisfy $PSL_2(\mathbf{Z}/6\mathbf{Z})=PSL_2(\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z})\times PSL_2(\mathbf{Z}/3\mathbf{Z})$. One option (not nice in the schematic point of view) is to quotient by the center, which is the set of scalar matrices $\mathrm{diag}(t,t)$ with $t^2=1$; probably it's fine here.

Comment: An interesting refinement of your question is whether a hyperbolic 3-manifold has a faithful representation into $PSL_2(\mathbb{C})$ with all integral traces. This is true for arithmetic and non-Haken hyperbolic 3-manifolds (actually, ones that contain no geometrically finite embedded surface). But there may be Haken 3-manifolds such that every representation is either non-integral or not faithful.

Comment: Example 5.2.8 (2) of MacLachlan-Reid (which is (10,1) surgery on the $5_2$ knot) might be a candidate for having no faithful integral $PSL_2$ representation. They prove this for the discrete faithful representation and Galois conjugates, and it appears from their discussion that there may not be any other representations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this follows easily from a couple of facts. The discrete faithful representation of an orientable hyperbolic 3-manifold leads to an embedding $\pi_1(M) \to PSL_2(S) \subset PSL_2(k)$, where $k$ is a number field, and $S$ is a finitely-generated subring (generated e.g. by the coefficients of matrices of generators). For most prime ideals $\mathcal{P} \subset \mathcal{O}_k$, $S$ will have non-negative valuation, and hence will lie in the valuation ring $R_{\mathcal{P}} \subset k_{\mathcal{P}}$ (the ring of $\mathcal{P}$-adic integers), hence $\pi_1(M) \hookrightarrow PSL_2(R_\mathcal{P})$. Such a field is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, where $\mathcal{P}|p$. (I'm attempting to follow the notation and results of Chapter 0.7 of [MacLachlan-Reid](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-6720-9)).

It's possible I've misinterpreted your notation. I'm interpreting your $K=k_\mathcal{P}, \mathcal{O}_K=R_\mathcal{P}$ (the valuation ring) to translate to MacLachlan-Reid's notation. If $\mathcal{O}_K$ does not denote the valuation ring, then I think you should clarify what you mean. This seems to me to be the only reasonable interpretation with $K=\mathbb{Q}_p, \mathcal{O}_K=\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Answer (score 11):

This does not answer the question but at least gives a counterexample to the conjecture in Luo's paper.

I assume that $\mathrm{PSL}_2(R)$ is defined as the quotient of $\mathrm{SL}_2(R)$ by its center, the set of matrices $\begin{pmatrix}t & 0\\ 0 & t\end{pmatrix}$, $t^2=1$. This has the property $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\prod_i R_i)=\prod_i\mathrm{PSL}_2(R_i)$.

Lemma 1: *let $G$ be a finitely generated group that is not embeddable into $\mathrm{PSL}_2$ over any field. Then $G\ast G$ is not embeddable into $\mathrm{PSL}_2$ over any commutative ring.*

Proof: embed $G\ast G$ into $\mathrm{PSL}_2(R)$; we can suppose that $R$ is finitely generated; let $N$ be the nilradical of $R$, so $N^k=0$ for some $k$ and it follows that the kernel of $\mathrm{PSL}_2(R)\to\mathrm{PSL}_2(R/N)$ is a nilpotent group. Since $|G|\ge 3$, $G\ast G$ has no nontrivial nilpotent normal subgroup. Hence the composite map $G\ast G\to\mathrm{PSL}_2(R/N)$ is injective. Now $R/N$ is a reduced commutative noetherian ring and hence is embeddable in a finite product of fields (since $R/N$ has finitely many minimal prime ideals, whose intersection is trivial). So we have an embedding of $G\ast G$ into a product $\prod_{i=1}^n\mathrm{PSL}_2(K_i)$. Now we use a general property: if a group $H$ has the property that any two nontrivial normal subgroups have nontrivial intersection, then whenever $H$ embeds into a direct product of two groups, the projection to at least one factor remains injective. This applies to the group $G\ast G$. Hence it embeds into $\mathrm{PSL}_2(K_i)$ for some $i$, contradicting the assumption. $\Box$

Now I apply this to $G$ the binary icosahedral group of order 120. Indeed this group cannot be embedded in $\mathrm{PSL}_2$ of any field. This is easy, showing (in arbitrary characteristic) that, unlike in $G$, the centralizer of any element of order 2 in $\mathrm{PSL}_2(K)$ is solvable.

Since $G$ is the $\pi_1$ of a closed 3-manifold, so is $G\ast G$, namely of the connected sum of two copies of the Poincaré manifold.

(Btw, I expect that $G$ itself is not embeddable in $\mathrm{PSL}_2$ of any finite commutative ring. It true this is probably not too hard -- one can suppose that the ring is local and I think I've checked the case of odd characteristic.)

---

**Edit**:

> the binary icosahedral group $G$ of order 120 indeed cannot itself be embedded into $\mathrm{PGL}_2(R)$ for any commutative ring $R$.

Here by $\mathrm{PGL}_2(R)$ I mean the quotient of $\mathrm{GL}_2(R)$ by its subgroup of scalar matrices $\begin{pmatrix}\nu & 0\\ 0 & \nu\end{pmatrix}$, $\nu\in R^\times$.

First, since the only nontrivial proper normal subgroup of $G$ is its center $\{1,z\}$ of order 2, a homomorphism from $G$ to another group is injective iff $z$ is not in the kernel.

Suppose by contradiction that $G$ is embedded into $\mathrm{PGL}_2(R)$, $R$ a commutative ring. Let $T=\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\ c & a+d\end{pmatrix}$ be a lift of the image of $z$. That $z$ is not in the kernel means that $T$ is not a scalar matrix, that is $(b,c,d)\neq (0,0,0)$ in $R^3$. We can assume that $R$ is a finitely generated ring, and then since any finitely generated commutative ring is residually finite (more generally any f.g. module over a noetherian commutative ring is residually of finite length), we can suppose that $R$ is finite. Since $R$ is then a product of local rings, we can suppose that $R$ is local, with maximal ideal $M$ and residual field $K=R/M$.

Since by the previous part of the post, $G$ cannot be embedded into $\mathrm{PGL}_2$ of a *field* (the argument being that in $\mathrm{PGL}_2(K)$, the centralizer of any nontrivial element is solvable), $T$ has to belong to the kernel of the map to $\mathrm{PGL}_2(K)$, so $(b,c,d)\in M^3$. Then we can replace $R$ by a proper quotient so as to assume that $Mb=Mc=Md=0$, and that $Rb+Rc+Rd$ has dimension 1 as vector space over $R/M$. That is, we can write $(b,c,d)=(\beta r,\gamma r,\delta r)$ with $r\in R$ with annihilator $M$ and $(\beta,\gamma,\delta)\in K^3\smallsetminus\{(0,0,0)\}$. To get a contradiction, let us check that the centralizer of $T$ in $\mathrm{PGL}_2(R)$ is solvable. It is enough to show that its inverse image $H$ in $\mathrm{GL}_2(R)$ is solvable. We have $H=\{h\in\mathrm{GL}_2(R):\exists q\in R^\times: hTh^{-1}=qT\}$. Note that since $a\in R^\times$, $q$ is unique, and the resulting map $H\to R^\times$, $h\mapsto q$ is a group homomorphism, whose kernel is the centralizer of $T$ in $\mathrm{GL}_2(R)$. But this centralizer is also the inverse image in in $\mathrm{GL}_2(R)$ of the centralizer of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0 & \beta\\ \gamma & \delta\end{pmatrix}$ in $\mathrm{GL}_2(K)$, and this is solvable since the latter matrix is not a scalar matrix.

Since $G$ is not solvable and $z$ is central, this is a contradiction.